# Syntax explaination for this time conversion

Tags: javascript

I do not understand this line of code. Can someone please explain character by character what it means in line 4?

```
hour = Math.floor(nextArrival / 3600);
min = Math.floor(nextArrival % 3600 / 60);
sec = Math.floor(nextArrival % 3600 % 60);
nextArrivalFinal2 = ((hour > 0 ? hour + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec);
```

How can I write it so that, when it is a new day and time is at 00:00:00, it will still display the 00 where the hours are suppose to be. Currently that code in line 4 skips displaying hours if it is I think under 1. So if the time is 00:05 AM, it will display only the minutes and seconds not the 00 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Its called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

#### Syntax:

```
(expression) ? true part : false part
```

This is more verbose approach for your line 4

```js
var nextArrivalFinal2 = ""
if (hours > 0) {
  nextArrivalFinal2 = hour + ":";
  if (min < 10)
    nextArrivalFinal2 += "0"
  else
    nextArrivalFinal2 += ""
} else {
  nextArrivalFinal2 += "";
}

nextArrivalFinal2 += min + ":";
if (sec < 10)
  nextArrivalFinal2 += "0"
else
  nextArrivalFinal2 += "";
nextArrivalFinal2 + sec
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is using the [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

`condition ? expr1 : expr2`

Using only `if` and `else` this would give something like this

```
if(hour > 0){
    text = hour + ":";  
    if(min < 10){
        text += "0"
    }else{
        text += ""
    }
    text += "";
}
text += min + ":";
if(sec < 10){
    text += "0";
}else{
    text += "";
}
text += sec;
```

Obviously there are useless `else` but I still show them to use every term of the conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

The others have explained line 4 very well, but for the last part of your question, you want something like consistent formatting as `hh:mm:ss` ?

```
nextArrivalFinal2 = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
```

Answer (score 0):

// example nextArrival = 3760 (this is the actual time in seconds)
//hour gives you the number of hours: 1 hour = 3600 sec

`hour = Math.floor(nextArrival / 3600);`

// getthe minutes : `nextArrival % 3600` will  give you the seconds removing the hours

`min = Math.floor(nextArrival % 3600 / 60);`

// this will give you the seconds

sec = Math.floor(nextArrival % 3600 % 60);

// 
nextArrivalFinal2 = ((hour > 0 ? hour + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec);

You must know about ternary operator
this is a basic ternary operator 
a>b ? a : b;

in this if a is greater than b  , then a is taken , else b is taken;

Similarly , in this case , if the `hour>0` the it goes to print `hour + some other values of minnutes which also have a ternary operator` else ""as  mentioned at line 10 in below code.
After that their is a + which means append to a string.
then it will  print value of min as shown in line 12 + the some sec value which will have again a ternary operator
and at  last it will print `sec` at line number 17

`((hour > 0 
    ? 
    hour + ":" + 
                    (min < 10 
                            ? 
                            "0" 
                            :
                             "") 
    :
     "") 
     + 
     min + ":" + (sec < 10 
                        ? 
                        "0" 
                        : 
                        "") 
     + sec)`